# JS: event listener on hidden element

Tags: javascript, performance

Do I need to `removeEventListener` when I change element's style `display:none`?
Do events effect page performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No **you don't actually need to**, specially if that element is going to be displayed again, because it wouldn't be cool to add/remove the listener every single time. Event listeners are asynchronous, and only impact on performance when they are executed, so **since that you're hiding that element (and the user isn't able to interact with it) your listener will not be called** as long as it stays hidden, **and there will not be any performance impact**.

Plus: even if you were completely removing that element using `parentEl.removeChild(childEl)`, you still wouldn't have needed to remove the listeners, because deleting an element will cause all its listeners to be removed as well.

Comment: @mcuong you're welcome. If my answer solved your question, I suggest you to mark it as correct so that future users with the same problem will find it easily.

Comment: not yet, I want to see more discussion :). I will mark your answer later :)

Comment: @mcuong Oh yes, seems legit then :)